# i am trying to use different inputs to search data from my database and keep all in session

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search data in php mysql using different input fields but my code seems correct but doesn't stay in session whenever i try to switch within pages...

```
    <form method="POST" action="search_all_properties">
   <div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="category" value="category" >
        <option selected>Category</option>
        <option value="houses">Houses</option>
        <option value="shops">Shops</option>
        <option value="office_spaces">Office Spaces</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="bedroom">
        <option selected>Bedrooms</option>
        <option value="1_bedroom">1 Bedroom</option>
        <option value="2_bedroom">2 Bedrooms</option>
        <option value="3_bedroom">3 Bedrooms</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="price">
        <option selected>Price</option>
        <option value="200,000">200,000</option>
        <option value="300,000">300,000</option>
        <option value="500,000">500,000</option>
        <option value="800,000">800,000</option>
        <option value="1_million">1 Million</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" onchange="trim(this)" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Location">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn bg-info">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
        </form>
```

i always get an error that some values are not defined...

```
$bedroom  = $database->escape_value($bedroom);
        $price    = $database->escape_value($price);
        $location = $database->escape_value($location);
```

The above variables are not defined each time i try to paginated to next page... session is for the variables are reset once i try to move to next page.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_SESSION['search'])){
        // 1. the current page number ($current_page)
        $page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
        // 2. records per page ($per_page)
        $per_page = 2;
        // 3. total record count ($total_count)
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $_SESSION['category']  = $_POST['category'];
            $category              = $_POST['category'];
            $_SESSION['bedroom']   = $_POST['bedroom'];
            $bedroom               = $_POST['bedroom']; 
            $_SESSION['price']     = $_POST['price'];
            $price                 = $_POST['price'];
            $_SESSION['location']  = $_POST['location'];
            $location              = $_POST['location'];
        } else { if(isset($_SESSION['category'])){
            $category         = $_SESSION['category'];
               }else if(isset($_SESSION['bedroom'])){
            $bedroom          = $_SESSION['bedroom'];
        }else if(isset($_SESSION['price'])){
            $price            = $_SESSION['price'];
        }else if(isset($_SESSION['location'])){
            $location         = $_SESSION['location'];
        }
        }  
        $category = $database->escape_value($category);
        $bedroom  = $database->escape_value($bedroom);
        $price    = $database->escape_value($price);
        $location = $database->escape_value($location); 

        $sql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pictures WHERE title LIKE '%$category%'";
        $sql .= " OR location LIKE '%$location%'";
        $sql .= " OR price LIKE '%$price%'";
        $sql .= " OR description LIKE '%$category%'";   
        $sql .= " OR bedroom LIKE '%$bedroom%'";
        $sql = $database->query($sql);
        $sql = $database->fetch_array($sql);
        $total_count = array_shift($sql);

        // Find all photos
        // use pagination instead
        $pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);
        // Instead of finding all records, just find the records

        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE title LIKE '%$category%'";
        $sql .= " OR location LIKE '%$location%'";
        $sql .= " OR price LIKE '%$price%'";    
        $sql .= " OR description LIKE '%$category%'";
        $sql .= " OR bedroom LIKE '%$bedroom%'";    
        $sql .= " ORDER by id DESC";
        $sql .= " LIMIT {$per_page}";
        $sql .= " OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
        $photos = Picture::find_by_sql($sql);
        $tcount = count($photos);   
        }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, share your error too.

Comment: `$database->escape_value()` I doubt this is enough to prevent SQL Injections. Use prepared statement with parameters instead

Comment: @Cid escape value is enough to escape it... i am just confused as to why session is reset as soon as i try to paginate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition to check the contents of the session variable won't work as you expect.

You are using `else if` which mean that `if(isset($_SESSION['category']))` is true, the remaining of the `else if` won't be executed.

The session is still saved, but only `category` is reached (because of the `else`)

Change your code to :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // your code
}
else
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['category'])) {
        $category         = $_SESSION['category'];
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['bedroom'])){
        $bedroom          = $_SESSION['bedroom'];
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['price'])){
        $price            = $_SESSION['price'];
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['location'])){
        $location         = $_SESSION['location'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why ?

Comment: yes i understand now... adding the else would break the session because it seem like the rest would have to meet the category condition... i may not have explained well but i understand... thanks

Comment: The session isn't broken, just the variables `$bedroom` and the others aren't defined. `$_SESSION['bedroom']` and the others still exist